# Debugging tomcat in Intelij

Tags: java, intellij-idea, tomcat

Не могу настроить debugg режим в idea для tomcat,
что я делел:

1)
 **For Windows**  Create the file "setenv.bat" if it does not exist already. Have it in the CATALINA_HOME/bin directory. And add this to the content:

> set JPDA_OPTS="-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket, address=9999,
>   server=y, suspend=n"
>   Although the settings can be put directly inside catalina.sh (or catalina.bat)

( и с помощью  файла `setenv.bat` и  `catalina.bat` результат одинаковый)

2) Click on Run ➝ Edit Configuration:
Click on the + button on the top left ➝ Tomcat Server ➝ Remote.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

3) стартую Tomcat в котором крутиться Warник
4) запускаю debugg.

output:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вот [тут](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6733849/remote-debugging-in-intellij-tomcat) посмотрите решение похожей проблемы.

Comment: А может быть просто 9999 порт занят?

Comment: пробовал разные порты

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я делаю это так:

1. Запускаю Tomcat командой ./catalina.sh jpda start или .\catalina.bat jpda start для Windows
2. В Idea создаю новую Run/Debug конфигурацию c типом "Remote"
3. В настройках нужно прописать правильный хост и исправить порт на 8000(debug порт по умолчанию у томката).

И собственно всё. Можно подключаться. Работает так же на Community версии.

Comment: помогло в моем случае 
 поменять set JPDA_OPTS="-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket, address=9999, server=y, suspend=n"  на
 set JAVA_OPTS=-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=9999 ,suspend=n,server=y